# How can I bake a metallic map off my model in Cycles?

Tags: materials, texture-baking, pbr

I have a model with several materials that I used to render a scene in Cycles. I wish now to put that model on SketchFab, but I need to bake my textures into single files for it. I successfully baked Roughness, Diffuse and Normals, but there's no option to bake metallic. How can I get this done?

Comment: Didi you figure out the right way to do it by any chance?

Answer (score 3):

Plug the metallic input into the roughness input of the principled shader and then bake the roughness map (texture) of the texture plugged in.
I hope it will work...

Comment: Or you could put it into diffuse and ignore all incoming light... but either works